# target of repeat operator is not specified when using optional character

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match a pattern like this:

```
ssfd
```

or this:

```
oifdsofijsdf d
```

So a first name alone or first name and middle initial.

```
"dsfsf m" =~ /^[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]$/
```

To make the middle initial optional, I added the ?:

```
"dsfsf" =~ /^[A-Za-z](+\s[A-Za-z])?$/
```

But it gives me error:

> target of repeat operator is not specified

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z])?$, try this one. you set a mistake postion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you misplaced the opening parenthesis and have a "1 or more" operator (`+`) right next to it, so the regex doesn't know what you can have one or more of:

```
^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z])?$
```

Is the regex you likely intended to use (and which seems to work on [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/3okvKCKsc2) for your test cases).

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[A-Za-z]+\s*[A-Za-z]*$/
```

`*` mean length is 0 or any